# How to install a .msi installer on remote windows machines without any prerequisites?

Tags: windows, installation, remote

I want to install a .msi installer (which is on my local computer and I can put it on a shared drive or local web server for direct download) on about 200 remote windows machines (Windows Server 2008, 2012, 2016 and 2019) and I have remote Desktop access to them and the machines are not members of a domain.
I tried PsExec and Invoke-Command but on most of the machines winrm is not installed/configured and on about all the machines PowerShell Remote is disabled and so I'm looking for a solution (PowerShell or CMD script) to install that installer in this situation.

Comment: PsExec doesn't use winrm at all and should work (given correct credentials and RPC access).

Comment: Given external RDP access (and credentials) you could use [rdpy](https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy) to run scripted commands on a list of machines.